# Question about write off someone

Tags: verbs

I read a sentence in a book, but I don't understand how I am supposed to understand this:

> I've never written someone off so quickly.

Is it in a good way? Or is it some irony?

Comment: Welcome to ELL. To understand this sentence, you only need to find "[write someone or something off](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/write+off)" in a dictionary (the one I linked to says "to drop someone or something from consideration").

Answer (score 1):

[to write someone off](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/write+off)

1. *to give up on turning someone or something into something*. I had to write Jill off as a future executive. The company wrote off the electric automobile as a dependable means of transportation. He would never work out. We wrote him off.
2. . *to give up on someone or something as a dead loss, waste of time, hopeless case, etc.* Don't write me off as a has-been. We almost wrote off the investment as a dead loss.

I think your case is the use of *to write someone off* explained at n.2

Comment: (Your dictionary answer is good, and I don't want to add another, but I think rusol could use some explainiation of his last two questions. Feel free to add to your answer.) You can replace "written someone off" with "given up on someone" to understand the meaning. I've never given up on someone so quickly. The sentence expresses frustration with disappointment.